# the summation of all proper divisors of a number

Tags: python

Problem is from online judge site. I have no idea how my code fails in the tests. I tried possible edge cases but https://www.spoj.com/problems/DIVSUM/, website still gave me error, At first try i went on brute force and loop throught 1 to input number, but efficiency was poor then i search how to develop better solution and found a really good solution to decrase complexity to sqrt(n).
Given a natural number n (1 <= n <= 500000), please output the summation of all its proper divisors.

Definition: A proper divisor of a natural number is the divisor that is strictly less than the number.

e.g. number 20 has 5 proper divisors: 1, 2, 4, 5, 10, and the divisor summation is: 1 + 2 + 4 + 5 + 10 = 22.

```
import math


def divisorSummation(inp):
    divisorsSum = 0
    if(inp == 1):
        return 0

    for i in range(1,  int(math.sqrt((inp)))+1):
        if(inp % i == 0):
            divisorsSum += i
            if(i*i != inp and i != 1):
                divisorsSum += inp / i

    return(int(divisorsSum))

value = int(input())
for i in range(value):
    (divisorSummation(int(input())))
```

Comment: If you stop at `sqrt(inp)` you'll miss some divisors. For instance, `sqrt(20)` is `4.47`, so you won't include `10`. That technique is only useful when looking for prime factors, not all divisors.

Comment: The same thing about the check `i*i != inp`

Comment: @Barmar: The branch with the `divisorsSum += inp / i` in it is supposed to handle divisors over the square root. That's where 10 goes into the sum if `inp` is `20`. Stopping at the square root is fine.

Comment: So, uh, Mocak... you forgot to print your output.

Comment: @Barmar Or you use this technique to find half of the divisors then use straight up division to find the other half. In fact, you have to do this for prime divisors as well. For example, 21 has prime divisors 3 and 7. So if you stop at `sqrt(n)`, you only find the 3. Then divide to get the 7.

Comment: @Mocak can you include an example where this code does not work?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Actually, it's only useful if you're just trying to test for primality. You don't need to find all the divisors for that, just one, and it will always be less than the sqrt.

Comment: Why are you adding `inp/i` to the sum? You should be adding `i`.

Comment: You can try this : `sum({i for a in range(1,int(20**0.5)+1) for i in (a, 20//a)  if 20%a == 0}) - 20` for `sqrt` case

Comment: @user2357112 How does that branch handle divisors over the sqrt? The `range()` expression stops at the sqrt, you never get to the `if` statement.

Comment: @Barmar Good point. And if you don't find a divisor less than `sqrt(n)`, you can declare `n` is prime.

Comment: @Barmar: Each divisor over the square root is equal to `inp/i` for some divisor `i` less than the square root.

Comment: @Barmar Each iteration of the loop sums most 2 elements to the list of divisors: `i` and `n/i`.

Comment: @Mocak, I just created an account on this website and submitted your code (with some added print statements) and my code was accepted. Is your issue actually that you're just not printing output?

Comment: `divmod` makes this simpler. `q, r = divmod(inp, i); if r == 0: divisorsSum += i + q`.

Comment: You can also use this as your stop condition (i.e., when `q > i`), saving you from having to compute a square root or performing an additional multiplication.

Comment: Thank you for all comments and opinions, missing part was printing the results, actually i printed it once but probably did something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works fine. In fact, I submitted your code (with modifications to include output) and it was accepted. Check https://www.spoj.com/status/ ID 30064357 for proof.

```
import math

def divisorSummation(inp):
    if inp == 1:
        return 0
    
    divisorsSum = 0
    for i in range(1, int(math.sqrt(inp)) + 1):
        if inp % i == 0:
            divisorsSum += i
            if i * i != inp and i != 1:
                divisorsSum += inp // i

    return divisorsSum    

for _ in range(int(input())):
    print(divisorSummation(int(input())))
```

Comment: It would be nice to apply at least basic formatting to this code, because OP obviously is learning python, and nice-looking code examples should be more useful.

Comment: @SUTerliakov Good idea, I cleaned it up a bit. If you have more formatting suggestions feel free to edit my answer.

Comment: Out of edit scope, but it may be better to begin with `divisorsSum = 1` and start iteration on 2 to avoid second comparison in a loop, because 1 is a proper divisor for all numbers greater than 1 (which is handled separately).